# Why the battery attributes are missing in android phones?

Tags: battery

on the android shell, when I executed following

```
>ls /sys/class/power_supply/battery
```

was expecting, current_now, power_now, charge_now or energy_now but I didn't find any *_now attribute other than voltage_now.

Could anyone help me to configure kernel in order to enable these (current_now, ..) attributes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No one answered my question, but I found the answer. I earned a badge Tumbleweed..lol

Because, battery drivers do not implement the same.